# sending a matrix to udf pig latin

Tags: hadoop, matrix, user-defined-functions, apache-pig

I have a problem with UDF pig latin.
I'm trying to implement a system that must verify if there is a "mapping" between a matrix stored in local and a set of matrices stored in an hadoop repository.
For mapping i mean if there exists a permutation of rows and columns of one stored matrix in hadoop that transform the matrix in a matrix equal to the one stored in local.
Because the matrices can have hundreds of elements, I was thinking to execute the mapping algorithm on hadoop to use parallelism.
I was looking to UDF pig latin, but i don't understand how to "send" the local matrix to the UDF function.

```
public class Mapping extends EvalFunc<String>
 {
private int[][] matrixToMap; //The local matrix i want to map

public String exec(Tuple input) throws IOException { //Here the tuple are the matrix stored in hadoop
  if (input == null || input.size() == 0)
      return null;
  try{
       //HERE THE CODE FOR THE MAPPING
  }

     }
   }
```

}

The problem I have is how i can initialize the attribute matrixToMap considering that I will use this code:

```
REGISTER /Users/myudfs.jar;  
//SOME CODE TO INITIALIZE ATTRIBUTE matrixToMap
records = LOAD 'Sample7.txt' //the matrix stored in hadoop
B = FOREACH records GENERATE myudfs.mapping(records);
```

Consider that the pig script is invoked in a java program, and that the local matrix is stored in a java matrix. So the java program looks like:

```
int [][] localMatrix;
pigServer.registerJar("/Users/myudfs.jar");
//Some code to make Mapping.matrixToMap = localMatrix
pigServer.registerQuery("records = LOAD 'Sample7.txt';");
pigServer.registerQuery("B = FOREACH records GENERATE myudfs.Mapping(formula);");
```

Do you have any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize class variables like that in the constructor of your UDF:

```
public class Mapping extends EvalFunc<String>
{
  private int[][] matrixToMap; //The local matrix i want to map

  public Mapping(String filename) {
    // Code to populate matrixToMap from the data in filename
  }

  public String exec(Tuple input) throws IOException { //Here the tuple are the matrix stored in hadoop
    if (input == null || input.size() == 0)
      return null;
    try{
       //HERE THE CODE FOR THE MAPPING
    }

   }
 }
```

In your script, use the following line:

```
DEFINE Mapping myudfs.Mapping('/path/to/matrix/on/HDFS');
```

With this method your matrix must be stored on HDFS, so that the mappers or reducers which are getting initialized and calling the constructor will have access to the data.

Comment: thank you for the answer, I appreciate. So if i understand, you suggest to:                                                          1) store the local matrix on hdfs                                    2) DEFINE Mapping myudfs.Mapping('/path/to/matrix/on/HDFS');                           3) pigServer.registerJar("/Users/myudfs.jar");                       4)pigServer.registerQuery("records = LOAD 'Sample7.txt';");

Comment: I missed the part about how you are invoking this through Java.  In that case I am not sure if the `DEFINE` statement will work as usual.  But give it a try.